# tests failing in react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have created a react app using a boilerplate create-react-app. I'm trying to write basic tests using `testing-library` but they are failing. 
I have a `Login` component which uses the `Alert` component to show an error message.

this is my `Login` component looks like

```
function Login({ onSubmit, error }) {
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    });

    const onFieldChange = ({ value }, field) => {
        let newCredentials = credentials;
        newCredentials[field] = value;
        setCredentials(newCredentials);
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h2 id="title">Login </h2>

            <form className="items" onSubmit={(event) => onSubmit(event, credentials)}>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" onChange={({ target }) => onFieldChange(target, 'username')} />
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={({ target }) => onFieldChange(target, 'password')} />
                {error && <Alert message={error} />}
                <button id="button" data-testid="submit">Submit</button>
                <a id="sign" type="submit" href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export { Login };
```

Alert component

```
const AlertError = styled.div`
        background-color: #f8d7da;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
`
const AlertMessage = styled.p`
        color: #721c24

`

const Container = styled.div(props => ({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: props.column && 'column'
}))

function Alert({ message }) {
    return (
        <AlertError>
            <AlertMessage role="alert" data-testid="alert">{message}</AlertMessage>
        </AlertError>
    )
}
```

App.test.js

```
describe('Login ', () => {
  let changeUsernameInput, changePasswordInput, clickSubmit, handleSubmit, alertRender;
  const { container, getByTestId, getByText, getByPlaceholderText, getByRole } = render(<Login onSubmit={handleSubmit} error={''} />);
  const user = { username: 'michelle', password: 'smith' }
  fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText(/username/i), { target: { value: user.username } })
  fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText(/password/i), { target: { value: user.password } })
  fireEvent.click(getByText(/submit/i))
  alertRender = getByRole('alert')  // breaks on this line
  it('should call onSubmit with the username and password', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

The following is the error I receive
`Unable to find an accessible element with the role "alert"`

**UPDATE**
As mentioned by @Christian the issue was `error` prop in Login component was not populated when I was trying to `get` its value so I had to query it only after submitting the form. Here's the full updated test file.

```
describe('Login ', () => {
  let changeUsernameInput, changePasswordInput, clickSubmit, handleSubmit, alertRender, error;
  handleSubmit = jest.fn()
  const { getByTestId, getByPlaceholderText, queryByTestId, rerender } = render(<Login onSubmit={handleSubmit} error={error} />);
  const user = { username: 'michelle', password: 'smith' }
  fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText(/username/i), { target: { value: user.username } })
  fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText(/password/i), { target: { value: user.password } })
  // fireEvent.click(getByText(/submit/i))
  fireEvent.submit(getByTestId(/login-form/i))

  // re-render the same component with different props
  error = 'The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again.'
  rerender(<Login onSubmit={handleSubmit} error={error} />)
  alertRender = queryByTestId('alert')
  console.log("alertRender:", alertRender.textContent)
  it('should call onSubmit with the username and password', () => {
    expect(alertRender.textContent).toBe(error)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the `<Alert />` component isn't visible because `error` is set to a blank string, and is therefore falsey.

When you write

```
error && <Alert message={error} />
```

The `<Alert />` is only shown when error is set.
From what I can see, you're not changing `error`.

The `getBy*` selectors from React Testing Library panic if the item doesn't exist.
If you don't want that, you can use `queryBy*` instead. Or you can pass in a non-empty value for `error`. I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Christian for the reply.  Ah! I forgot to add the `fireEvent.click` line here before querying the alert. I've updated the question please have a look. Also, I had to re-render the component with updated props because after "submission" the props get updated and now its working. Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I think your test name is a bit misleading, though. `it('should call onSubmit...')` should probably be renamed to `it('shows the error if there is one')`, if you want to keep the same content. To check that `onSubmit` is called, you can use Jest's `expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()`